# Not working PHP form on my site

Tags: php, html, forms

HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form footer-form" method="post" action="contact.php">
...
</form><!-- /.footer-form -->
```

contact.php:

```
<?php

/******************************************************************
 * Requirements
 ******************************************************************/
require_once 'libraries/swift/lib/swift_required.php';

/******************************************************************
 * Constants
 ******************************************************************/
define('MESSAGE_SUBJECT', 'Subject');
define('MESSAGE_FROM_EMAIL', 'john@doe.com');
define('MESSAGE_FROM_NAME', 'John Doe');
define('MESSAGE_TO_EMAIL', 'john@doe.com');

define('TRANSPORT_SERVER', 'smtp.example.com');
define('TRANSPORT_PORT', 25);
define('TRANSPORT_USERNAME', 'username');
define('TRANSPORT_PASSWORD', 'password');

/******************************************************************
 * Configure transport
 ******************************************************************/
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(TRANSPORT_SERVER, TRANSPORT_PORT)
    ->setUsername(TRANSPORT_USERNAME)
    ->setPassword(TRANSPORT_PASSWORD);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

/******************************************************************
 * Send email
 ******************************************************************/
if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $body = sprintf("Email: %s \nName: %s\nBody: %s", $_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['message']);

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject(MESSAGE_SUBJECT)
        ->setFrom(array(MESSAGE_FROM_EMAIL => MESSAGE_FROM_NAME))
        ->setTo(array(MESSAGE_TO_EMAIL))
        ->setBody($body);

    $mailer->send($message);
}
```

But when I fill my form end put the enter, get 'not found contact.php' error. (My real email infos are on Gmail and opened IMAP) Again and again I checked my details, everything is OK.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are contact.php and the html in the same directory?

Comment: I don't know what your directory structure looks like but try changing it to ./contact.php. Otherwise make sure it's pointing to the directory where contact.php exists.

Comment: The web server can't find the file.  Check the request being made, check that it maps to the file's location on the server, check the web server's logs for additional information, check file permissions, etc.  All we can tell you is that the web server doesn't think `contact.php` is where you think it is.

Comment: Thank you friends. However, contact.php root directory so contact.php and html in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

Are these two files you are refering to in the same directory? Try changing contact.php to /contact.php as shown below

```
<form class="contact-form footer-form" method="post" action="/contact.php">
```

or, just feature a full uri

```
<form class="contact-form footer-form" method="post" action="FULLURL/contact.php">
```